# Best Way to read rss feed in .net Using C#

Tags: c#, rss, xmltextreader

What is the best way to read *RSS feeds*?

I am using `XmlTextReader` to achieve this. Is there any other best way to do it?

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(strURL);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader);
```

After reading the *RSS feed* using `XmlTextReader`, is there any way I can populate data to `ListItem` instead of `DataSet`?

[image]

Answer (score 200):

Add `System.ServiceModel` in references

Using [`SyndicationFeed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):

```
string url = "http://fooblog.com/feed";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    String subject = item.Title.Text;    
    String summary = item.Summary.Text;
    ...                
}
```

Comment: This is the schizzle.  Awesome and succinct.  You also need to be using System.Xml; but that's fairly evident. For Blogger the url is currently "http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" (Atom 1.0) and "http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" for RSS 2.0.  The SyndicationItem item has all the item properties you'll need.  Just examine the object in the Visual Studio debugger and be illuminated.

Comment: can we use XmlTextReader instead of xmlreader any performance difference?

Comment: For .Net Core, the NuGet Package you want to install to use this is `System.ServiceModel.Syndication`

Comment: for 2019 this blows up every time I try to access the only version which is prerelease.

Comment: For me the below error is thrown with the above code.

System.Xml.XmlException: 'For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.'

Answer (score 11):

This is an old post, but to save people some time if you get here now like I did, I suggest you have a look at the **CodeHollow.FeedReader** package which supports a wider range of RSS versions, is easier to use and seems more robust. https://github.com/codehollow/FeedReader

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the [`SyndicationFeed` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx), which does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
private string GetAlbumRSS(SyndicationItem album)
    {

        string url = "";
        foreach (SyndicationElementExtension ext in album.ElementExtensions)
            if (ext.OuterName == "itemRSS") url = ext.GetObject<string>();
        return (url);

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string albumRSS;
        string url = "http://www.SomeSite.com/rss‎";
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(url);
        SyndicationFeed albums = SyndicationFeed.Load(r);
        r.Close();
        foreach (SyndicationItem album in albums.Items)
        {

            cell.InnerHtml = cell.InnerHtml +string.Format("<br \'><a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", album.Links[0].Uri, album.Title.Text);
            albumRSS = GetAlbumRSS(album);

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: This supports only with UWP - **Windows Community Toolkit**

There is a much easier way now. You can use the [RssParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/parsers/rssparser?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5001828) class. The sample code is given below.

```
public async void ParseRSS()
{
    string feed = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            feed = await client.GetStringAsync("https://visualstudiomagazine.com/rss-feeds/news.aspx");
        }
        catch { }
    }

    if (feed != null)
    {
        var parser = new RssParser();
        var rss = parser.Parse(feed);

        foreach (var element in rss)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Title: {element.Title}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Summary: {element.Summary}");
        }
    }
}
```

For non-UWP use the Syndication from the namespace `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` as others suggested.

```
public static IEnumerable <FeedItem> GetLatestFivePosts() {
    var reader = XmlReader.Create("https://sibeeshpassion.com/feed/");
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    return (from itm in feed.Items select new FeedItem {
        Title = itm.Title.Text, Link = itm.Id
    }).ToList().Take(5);
}

public class FeedItem {
    public string Title {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Link {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```