# Install ASP.NET 5.0 version of System.ServiceModel.Syndication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, rss

I'm building a C# class in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6, within an ASP.NET Web Application project (it's MVC). The class needs to read RSS feeds, and according to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399400/best-way-to-read-rss-feed-in-net-using-c-sharp), the best way to do this is via the `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` namespace.

I tried adding the DLL needed for this by right-clicking `References` under the `web.app` folder in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. Then I selected *Add Reference...* In the dialog box, it didn't have any ASP.NET 5.0 libraries listed; it only had the 4.0 version of various libraries listed. So I added `System.ServiceModel` (4.0.0.0).

Now Visual Studio is throwing these errors:

```
...\src\web.app\Models\RssFeedModels.cs(4,14): ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
...\src\web.app\Models\RssFeedModels.cs(21,17): ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SyndicationFeed' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
...\src\web.app\Models\RssFeedModels.cs(25,20): ASP.NET Core 5.0 error CS0103: The name 'SyndicationFeed' does not exist in the current context
```

Here's my `RssFeedModels.cs` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;

namespace web.app.Models
{
    public class Rss
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ContentSnippet { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class RssFeedModels
    {
        private XmlReader reader;
        private SyndicationFeed feed;

        public RssFeedModels(string url) {
            reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
            feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this issue? Thank you.

**Update**: Modified the `project.json` file as recommended by `heymega`. Here's what the `project.json` file's pertinent section looks like:

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
    "run": "run"
},

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { },
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"
        },
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    }
},
```

This throws many errors, starting with this:

```
The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) web.app.DNX 4.5.1
```

Comment: I have created an Issue on the DNX Core WCF GitHub page [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/76). Please add your support.

Comment: Did you solved this "ServiceModel" issue? I want to use "ServiceModel" to communicate with windows service from vnext web app, but having similar errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.ServiceModel` hasn't been ported to `ASP.NET 5` yet so you can't use it as part of the core library.

You should be able to include the reference for a standard `aspnet50` project (Not core).

```
{
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"
            },
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413756/asp-net-5-add-wcf-service-reference) when trying to add a WCF service reference.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this goes into the `project.json` file.

Comment: How do you modify the project.json file? It already has items in it. Do we just add this to it? Thanks

Comment: Yes - You manually add or remove dependencies from project.json. Visual studio watches for changes in that file and will add and remove the actual references behind the scenes. Give it a go :)

Comment: It throws 1167 errors when I add the above code to the `project.json` file. Please see my update to the question above.