# System.Runtime.Serialization could not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Just as title says, trying to create ASP.NET Core application, or more correctly, migrating from RC2 to Core 1.0.

Got a second construction in project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

There are no problems if I remove imports and revert `netcoreapp1.0` to `net451` (just like it was before migration attempt) but in the current state I am receiving two issues:

```
NU1001  The dependency System.Runtime.Serialization >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.
NU1001  The dependency System.ServiceModel >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.
```

I also cant just remove them and hope that nothing will happen because after removal, I am receiving a bunch of `are you missing an assembly reference` issues.

What possibly am I missing to fix this issue?

***EDIT***

Tried to add to dependecies `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives`. Well, it worked out exactly as if I removed `System.Runtime.Serialization`.

In project I got  such issues as:

```
The type or namespace name 'Mime' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
```

and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search shows

### [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/319)

> According to a Microsoft blog post, binary serialization was
>   purposefully removed from .NET Core, yet the namespace for it is still
>   documented.

Answer from there:

> Binary serialization was removed, but the types listed are still
>   included. According to package search, a lot of the types are in the
>   `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives` package. And after adding
>   `"System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.0-beta-23516"` to
>   dependencies in project.json, `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`
>   compiles fine for me.

---

It appears [System.ServiceModel hasn't made it to Core yet, quote below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263354/542251):

> `System.ServiceModel` hasn't been ported to ASP.NET 5 yet so you can't
>   use it as part of the core library.
>
> You should be able to include the reference for a standard aspnet50
>   project (Not core).

Comment: Wow... I actually was looking into System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives but wasnt sure about its containment. Gonna try it now.

Comment: Tried System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives and still got a bunch of missing assembly references. Some of them are very strange. For example, 'System.Net.Mime'. Also, System.ServiceModel are still dead

Comment: They've moved a lot of stuff around in Core, it's pretty much the point of it TBH (break up the System namespace, etc.). Your likely going to need to find each missing assembly manually. Also don't neccasarily expect them all to be there. Core is pretty much a re-write and it's also still a work in progress. It appears [System.ServiceModel hasn't made it to Core yet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30263354/542251). Personally I'm not touching Core until it's a couple of iterations in, I'm old enough to remember .Net 1.0 and it's missing....features...

Comment: Well, the funny thing is that I can move dependencies into `netcoreapp` and then make `net451` in framework just to get those references... and it will work... but by doing this it makes migrating so pointless... well I guess ill wait a little bit more. Thank for answer and for your time.

Comment: Yeah. I mean thats what I mean. Really it's still bedding in. IMO The only time I'd explicitly use core right now is if I needed it to run on Linux.