# How to collect news from different websites

Tags: java, c#, android

I am starting working on a new app which will show news of different channels. But I am bit confused that how to get data from websites which will update automatically. Am I need their API keys for integration or some other method. please give me some suggestions.

Comment: It depends on sites. If they have rss or other api use it. Straightforward way is to user Html Agility Pack and parse news pages.

Comment: You can use Rss feed that website is providing for other websites.

Answer (score 4):

News sites will likely have RSS feeds. You can use classes from [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse them. In-depth discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399400/best-way-to-read-rss-feed-in-net-using-c-sharp).